# Fitbit collect data from Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fitbit

I want to take fitbit data(like heart rate or profile data) from fitbit server to my own android App.Can you send me a simple example or give me directions on how to achive this?
Thanks a lot.

I tried using FitbitApi20 from github but does not work for me.

Comment: I think your question is too broad for SO. Refer to [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Here is a quote: _Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much._ I believe you're asking someone to write an app for you. I don't think that's how SO works. Usually you post code you wrote that doesn't work correctly and people help you fix it. I suggest that you take the [tour] in order to understand how SO works.